# How to show data in select option based on array unique id in vue js

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, multidimensional-array, select-options

In my Vue components, I have two array called categories and product which is coming from the DB. The categories array is an array of objects like its have id, type, name, value, and products array also have id, type, name, parent_id, value.
parent_id in products is the id of categories. I want to show the products based on categories in the select option. like If categories type A then products will be B, C, D, or If categories type B then products will be X, Y, Z.
How can I do that?

Comment: please provide your code - otherwise it's difficult to understand your problem.. and we could not help you out!

Comment: I am sorry to say i tried provide my code in comments section but failed to do that
Is there option or place to provide the code

Comment: just for additional info - you can edit your question afterwards as well and put in your code :) please take time and read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for your next question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Step 1:*** Create an `html` template with `select` option

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="row">
      <label>Category </label>
      <select @change="onChangeCategory" v-model="selectedCategory">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
        <option
          v-for="(category, index) in categories"
          :key="index"
          :value="category">
          {{ category.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label>Product </label>
      <select v-model="selectedProduct">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
        <option
          v-for="(product, index) in filteredProducts"
          :key="index"
          :value="product">
          {{ product.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <p v-if="selectedCategory">Selected Category {{ selectedCategory }}</p>
    <p v-if="selectedProduct">Selected Product {{ selectedProduct }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

***Step 2:*** Create an model `data`

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedCategory: "",
    selectedProduct: "",
    filteredProducts: [],
    categories: [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: "Food",
        name: "Food",
        value: "Food",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        type: "Drinks",
        name: "Drinks",
        value: "Drinks",
      },
    ],
    products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: "Food",
        name: "Chiken 65",
        parent_id: 1,
        value: "001",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        type: "Food",
        name: "Magie",
        parent_id: 1,
        value: "002",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        type: "Food",
        name: "Mutton Roast",
        parent_id: 1,
        value: "003",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        type: "Drinks",
        name: "Pepsi",
        parent_id: 2,
        value: "004",
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        type: "Drinks",
        name: "Beer",
        parent_id: 2,
        value: "005",
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        type: "Drinks",
        name: "7Up",
        parent_id: 2,
        value: "006",
      },
    ],
  };
},
```

***Step 3:*** Add an `onChange` event for category

```
methods: {
  onChangeCategory() {
    this.selectedProduct = "";
    this.filteredProducts = this.products.filter((item) => {
      return item.parent_id === this.selectedCategory.id;
    });
  },
},
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-butterfly-zsz2t)

Comment: @AshrafulAlamShihab Its my pleasure. Accept the answer and give a thumbs up! Thank you.